# tf.train.shuffle_batch doen't seem to produce random images

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm loading TFRecords and I have 6 different classes and a total of about 8000 images.

Here is what my current arguments look like:

```
images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, 
capacity=3000, num_threads=3, min_after_dequeue=2000)
```

Here are the images I am producing:

```
10, 299, 299, 3)
[1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
(10, 299, 299, 3)
[2 2 0 2 0 2 1 0 0 2]
(10, 299, 299, 3)
[0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2]
(10, 299, 299, 3)
[0 0 2 0 2 2 0 1 1 0]
(10, 299, 299, 3)
[0 2 0 0 2 0 0 2 1 2]
```

As you can see by the labels, I'm only getting images from the first three
classes.

Are there certain values or ratios to use with capacity and min_after_dequeue? 
(I tried really upping both values but my PC seemed to slowed down considerably, I may need to restart and try again)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TensorFlow API webpage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch) says

`min_after_dequeue`: Minimum number elements in the queue after a dequeue, used to ensure a level of mixing of elements.

`capacity`: The maximum number of elements in the queue.

So, you should increase `min_after_dequeue` (e.g. `8000`) and make sure `capacity` is greater or equal to `min_after_dequeue`.